# How can I create a Java algorithm that takes any number of players and pair them up any number of times uniquely?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am looking to create an algorithm in Java that can take any number of "players" and group them up a specified number of times each. However, two pairs cannot be the same. So, if we are supplied 9 players (dubbed 0, 1, 2, etc) by the user and each player should be paired 3 times, that means that this algorithm needs to be able to generate a list of pairs where each player is paired 3 times.

So 4 players being paired two times could be: {{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {0, 2}, {1, 3}}.

Obviously, it can be impossible in some scenarios (like 4 players being uniquely paired 20 times), but I have input restrictions to combat that.

{0, 1} and {1, 0} are equal pairs. The order of the numbers does not matter, they are not unique.

The preferable way for input is just given two numbers (number of players, number of pairs per players) and the preferable way for the output to be given is in a two dimensional array of integers (each player being dubbed by an integer), like I gave an example of.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this? Pseudo-code, actual code, any ideas are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, questions in this form are off-topic.  Please read [ask].  We won't do your work or research for you.

Comment: @JimGarrison This isn't for work or research, this is for a personal project I'm doing. This really isn't a complex algorithm, you think I'm being paid to make this?

Comment: That's not the point.  Stack Overflow isn't a discussion forum... please read [ask], take the [tour] and visit the [help].  Also, [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Comment: @JimGarrison How is this not an actual question? I did read the how to ask site, this question follows those guidelines. It asks for either the general format or the code of a specific algorithm. This is not "can someone help me" unless you constitute any question that the poster benefits from as begging for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is valid and interesting to solve in code.

This is why I coded that whole thing.

There's one downside to my solution, or rather: the problem.
In certain situations, some players can have many matches between them, while others have little. So in the end, some players might not get matched properly.

In this case, you'd need a mathematical trick, or a backtracking algorithm, that steps back on parts of the solution and tries (brute-forces) other combinations. My algorithm has neither, but it indicates Exceptions and validity.

Also check the comments in the code.

```
package snippet;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class BadPairingStuff6 {



    static class Player {

        public final int                mID;
        private final BadPairingStuff6  mParentLogic;

        public int mMatches;

        public Player(final int pID, final BadPairingStuff6 pBadPairingStuff5) {
            mID = pID;
            mParentLogic = pBadPairingStuff5;
        }

        @Override public int hashCode() {
            return mID;
        }
        @Override public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) return true;
            if (obj == null) return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
            final Player other = (Player) obj;
            if (mID != other.mID) return false;
            return true;
        }
        @Override public String toString() {
            return "Player[" + mID + "]";
        }

        public void incMatches() {
            ++mMatches;
        }
        public int getMatches() {
            return mMatches;
        }
        public boolean canPlayAnotherMatch() {
            return getMatches() < mParentLogic.mPairingsAllowed;
        }
    }

    static class Pairing {
        public final Player mPlayer1;
        public final Player mPlayer2;

        public Pairing(final Player pPlayer1, final Player pPlayer2) {
            if (pPlayer1.mID < pPlayer2.mID) {
                mPlayer1 = pPlayer1;
                mPlayer2 = pPlayer2;
            } else {
                mPlayer1 = pPlayer2;
                mPlayer2 = pPlayer1;
            }
        }

        @Override public String toString() {
            return mPlayer1 + "+" + mPlayer2;
        }

        @Override public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + mPlayer1.mID;
            result = prime * result + mPlayer2.mID;
            return result;
        }

        @Override public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) return true;
            if (obj == null) return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
            final Pairing other = (Pairing) obj;
            if (mPlayer1 != other.mPlayer1) return false;
            if (mPlayer2 != other.mPlayer2) return false;
            return true;
        }
    }

    static class PartnerMap {
        private final HashMap<Player, ArrayList<Player>> mMap = new HashMap<>();

        public PartnerMap(final Iterable<Player> pPlayers) {
            for (final Player player : pPlayers) {
                final ArrayList<Player> partners = new ArrayList<>();
                for (final Player partner : pPlayers) {
                    if (player != partner) partners.add(partner);
                }
                mMap.put(player, partners);
            }
        }

        public Player getPartner(final Player pPlayer) {
            final ArrayList<Player> possiblePartners = mMap.get(pPlayer);
            if (possiblePartners.size() < 1) throw new NotEnoughPartnersException(pPlayer);
            return possiblePartners.get((int) (Math.random() * possiblePartners.size()));
        }
        public void removePartners(final Player pPlayer, final Player pPartner) {
            System.out.println("\t\tBadPairingStuff5.PartnerMap.removePartners(" + pPlayer + ", " + pPartner + ")");

            System.out.println("\t\t\tRemoving for " + pPlayer);
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\tBEFORE: " + toString(mMap.get(pPlayer)));
            mMap.get(pPlayer).remove(pPartner);
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\tAFTER: " + toString(mMap.get(pPlayer)));

            System.out.println("\t\t\tRemoving for " + pPartner);
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\tBEFORE: " + toString(mMap.get(pPartner)));
            mMap.get(pPartner).remove(pPlayer);
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\tAFTER: " + toString(mMap.get(pPartner)));
        }

        static String toString(final Iterable<Player> pPlayers) {
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("[");
            for (final Player player : pPlayers) {
                sb.append(player.mID + " ");
            }
            sb.append("]");
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public void removePlayerCompletely(final Player pPlayer) {
            System.out.println("\t\t\tBadPairingStuff5.PartnerMap.removePlayerCompletely(" + pPlayer + ")");
            for (final ArrayList<Player> partnerMap : mMap.values()) {
                partnerMap.remove(pPlayer);
            }
            mMap.get(pPlayer).clear();
        }

        public void print() {
            System.out.println("Partner Map");
            for (final Entry<Player, ArrayList<Player>> e : mMap.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("\t" + e.getKey());
                for (final Player v : e.getValue()) {
                    System.out.println("\t\t" + v);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public static class NotEnoughPartnersException extends IllegalStateException {
        private static final long   serialVersionUID    = -7249807214069096317L;
        private final Player        mPlayer;
        public NotEnoughPartnersException(final Player pPlayer) {
            super("Not enough partners available for " + pPlayer + "!");
            mPlayer = pPlayer;
        }
        public Player getPlayer() {
            return mPlayer;
        }
    }

    static class PairingResult {
        public final ArrayList<Pairing>     mCreatedPairings;
        public final ArrayList<Exception>   mExceptions;
        public PairingResult(final ArrayList<Pairing> pCreatedPairings, final ArrayList<Exception> pExceptions) {
            mCreatedPairings = pCreatedPairings;
            mExceptions = pExceptions;
        }
        public boolean isValid() {
            return mExceptions.size() < 1;
        }
    }



    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final int players = 10;
        final int pairingsAllowed = 4;
        final PairingResult result = new BadPairingStuff6(players, pairingsAllowed).createPairings();

        System.out.println("All pairings:");
        final HashMap<Long, Long> playCounter = new HashMap<>();
        for (final Pairing p : result.mCreatedPairings) {
            System.out.println("\t" + p);

            {
                final Long oldCount = playCounter.get(Long.valueOf(p.mPlayer1.mID));
                playCounter.put(Long.valueOf(p.mPlayer1.mID), Long.valueOf(oldCount == null ? 1 : (oldCount.longValue() + 1)));
            }
            {
                final Long oldCount = playCounter.get(Long.valueOf(p.mPlayer2.mID));
                playCounter.put(Long.valueOf(p.mPlayer2.mID), Long.valueOf(oldCount == null ? 1 : (oldCount.longValue() + 1)));
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Pairings per Player: ");
        for (final Entry<Long, Long> e : playCounter.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("\t" + e.getKey() + " -> " + e.getValue());
        }

        System.out.println("Exceptions:");
        System.out.flush();
        sleep();
        for (final Exception e : result.mExceptions) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.err.flush();
        sleep();

        System.out.println("Valid result: " + result.isValid());
        System.out.println("All done.");
    }



    /*
     * OBJECT
     */



    final int mPairingsAllowed;

    private final ArrayList<Player> mPlayers = new ArrayList<>();

    public BadPairingStuff6(final int pPlayersCount, final int pPairingsAllowed) {
        mPairingsAllowed = pPairingsAllowed;

        // create players
        for (int i = 0; i < pPlayersCount; i++) {
            mPlayers.add(new Player(i, this));
        }
    }



    public PairingResult createPairings() {
        final ArrayList<Pairing> createdPairings = new ArrayList<>();
        final ArrayList<Exception> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();
        final PartnerMap possiblePairings = new PartnerMap(mPlayers);

        final HashSet<Player> playersToHandle = new HashSet<>(mPlayers);
        while (!playersToHandle.isEmpty()) {

            final ArrayList<Player> removePlayersPerRound = new ArrayList<>();
            for (final Player player : playersToHandle) {
                if (!player.canPlayAnotherMatch()) {
                    possiblePairings.removePlayerCompletely(player);
                    removePlayersPerRound.add(player);
                    continue;
                }

                try {
                    System.out.println("Creating matches for " + player + " (" + player.getMatches() + ")");

                    final Player partner = possiblePairings.getPartner(player);
                    if (!partner.canPlayAnotherMatch()) continue;

                    final Pairing newPairing = new Pairing(player, partner);
                    if (createdPairings.contains(newPairing)) System.out.println("WARNING! Double hit for " + newPairing);
                    createdPairings.add(newPairing);
                    possiblePairings.removePartners(player, partner);
                    player.incMatches();
                    partner.incMatches();
                    System.out.println("\tMatched with " + partner);

                    if (!partner.canPlayAnotherMatch()) {
                        possiblePairings.removePlayerCompletely(partner);
                        removePlayersPerRound.add(partner);
                    }

                } catch (final NotEnoughPartnersException e) {
                    // the flushes and sleeps are only a cheap shot to keep System.out and System.err outputs in somewhat chronological order.
                    // this is for proof/debug/answer only, and should NOT be used in production!
                    System.out.flush();
                    sleep();

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //              throw e; // if you want to abort early
                    removePlayersPerRound.add(e.getPlayer());
                    exceptions.add(e);

                    System.err.flush();
                    sleep();
                }
            }

            playersToHandle.removeAll(removePlayersPerRound);
        }

        possiblePairings.print();

        return new PairingResult(createdPairings, exceptions);
    }



    // the sleeps are only a cheap shot to keep System.out and System.err outputs in somewhat chronological order.
    // this is for proof/answer only, and should NOT be used in production
    static void sleep(final long pMilliSec) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(pMilliSec);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e1) { /* */ }
    }
    static void sleep() {
        sleep(100);
    }



}
```

I use lots of inner static classes. This is for demonstration purposes only.
If you want to actually use those classes, put each of them into its separate file (remove the "static class", and add a "public class" where it's missing).

Also note that this complexity is needed for random assignments. If the algorithm could always churn out the same combinations, it would be about 1/10th of the code.